# Is it late to seed? weather 90s , end of May.

Tags: lawn, grass, seeds, germination, overseeding

I bought Turf Builder Grass Seed Sun and Shade Mix for my yard. I live in Kansas City and weather was around 70s but now all the sudden 90s and seems like it will be 90s for a while. Can I seed now or is it too hot. I can water 2-3 times a day to keep them moist. I will also use turf builder starter fertilizer.  I did rake my old grass and got rid of the dead grass. Some areas overseeding some areas I don't have grass. I had to wait because I applied weed killer late and had to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a warm spell it will pass. Yes you can seed.fall seeding is best.